# Ubuntu SDK suggests that I develop for 32 bit systems

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, ubuntu-sdk

I'm developing a software using ubuntu sdk, it suggest that I develop it for 32 bit systems, I'm on 64 bit, will it work on 64 bit systems without adding architecture i386? Moreover is it worth developing for 32 bit systems nowadays? doesn't pretty much everyone uses 64 bit?

It clearly suggest to download the 32 bit libraries in the installation wizard. I'm developing HTML5 app.

And I'm developing it for 14.04 since this is my system, can I somewhat guarantee that it will work for other ubuntu releases? Maybe debian too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's still quite a lot machines that runs on the 32 bit architecture. (Quite alot of people i know, still runs on the 32 bit architecture.) So it would be a good choice to make it available for those people. Ubuntu usually comes preloaded with the libraries needed to run 32 bit applications, in a 64 bit environment.
If it refuses to run, install the ia32 library, using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

And for the last question, no. You won't be able to 100% guarantee it to work out of the box on all linux distros, as some come with other packages preloaded.